# Dafny 3 maximum int constant

Tags: dafny

I there in Dafny 3 a maximum/minimum int constant? something like int.MaxValue?

I need it to write a Dafny program that calculates the minimum value in a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

In Dafny, the type int is meant to model mathematical integers. There is no maximum or minimum int constant.

If you want to work with a range of integers, you can define it using a [newtype](https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-newtypes) declaration. The [Dafny library](https://github.com/dafny-lang/libraries/blob/master/src/BoundedInts.dfy) also contains some standard definitions such as 32 bits integers.

As for finding the minimum int in a sequence, you could do something along these lines:

```
datatype Option<T> =
    | Some(value: T)
    | None
    
function FindMinRec(s: seq<int>, lb: int): int {
    if |s| == 0 then lb
    else if s[0] < lb
        then FindMinRec(s[1..],s[0])
        else FindMinRec(s[1..],lb)
}

function FindMin(s: seq<int>): Option<int> {
    if |s| == 0 then None else Some(FindMinRec(s[1..],s[0]))
}
```